# acces getFieldDecorator antd 3x

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I am trying to acces the property getFieldDecorator in antd 3x in a React functional component, however I am not managing to do so, I have been googleing around for some time and couldnt find any reference about using getFieldDecorator with stateless components( functional components), I was wondering if anyone ran into the same issue and if you managed to solve it without having to change to class component.

My code is very simple, an input wrapped inside a Form.Item

```
const FormItem = Form.Item

const inviteModal = ( {props}) => {
return(
  <Form layout="vertical">
             <FormItem>
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: i18n.t('email'),
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input type="text" placeholder="email" />)}
            </FormItem> 
          
     )
}


export default Form.create()(inviteModal)
```

trying to acces 'props' gives undefined, also writting my export default like:

```
export default Form.create({getFieldDecorator})(inviteModal)
```

does not work neither.

I will probably use class components for the forms, but I would appreciate if anyone can carify to me for the shake of learning.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is posible, the only problem is how  was importing the props, so basically to use it you have to access the props object from the component like:

```
const InviteModal = (props) => {
  const {getFieldDecorator} = props.form
```

and there you go, nice and working, hope this can help someone else